# How to prevent Node.js sending success header to ajax post request

Tags: ajax, node.js

I am trying to send a success status to the ajax request using `res.end('{"success" : "Updated Successfully", "status" : 200}');` but run into this error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. Basically when the user data is saved on the server I want ajax to refresh the page, although, I think somewhere in this in the app.post a success message is being sent before I try to manually do it. How can I prevent any success message being sent to the ajax post request so I can do it manually.

```
app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
var userDetails = User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password1, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))
});

User.findOne({
    $or: [{
        'username': req.body.username
    }, {
            'email': req.body.email
        }]
}, function (err, user) {
    if (user) {
        if (allClients.indexOf(req.body.socket)) {
            if (user.username === req.body.username) {
                io.to(req.body.socket).emit('userInfo', 'That username is already in use.');
            } else {
            }
            if (user.email === req.body.email) {
                io.to(req.body.socket).emit('userInfo', 'That email is already in use.');
            } else {
            }
        } else {
            console.log('timeout error 822')
        }
    } else {
        req.login(userDetails, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                userDetails.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.end('{"success" : "Updated Successfully", "status" : 200}');
                    res.redirect('/');
                });
            } else {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    }
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    }
});
});
```

This is my ajax request

```
 $("#form1").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            datatype: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: '/signup',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result)
            {
                console.log(result);
                if(result.status == 200){
                    window.location.reload(true); 
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you using Express? If so you can use `res.status(200).send("Updated successfully");` Note that by default res.send() will return 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the code:

```
res.end('{"success" : "Updated Successfully", "status" : 200}');                  
res.redirect('/');
```

Replace the above with only

```
res.status(200).send({"success" : "Updated Successfully", "status" : 200})
```

res.redirect is to take the user to another page(it calls a get route). The error you are getting is because node is confused between sending the response back to ajax or to redirect.